# Ubuntu 18.04 -How to abort a fail installation of Oracle's Virtualbox 5.2

Tags: apt, virtualbox, oracle

I tried to install VirtualBox `apt-get install virtualbox`. Installation froze at roughly 79%. I had to kill its process. Now every time I want to `apt-get update`, it tries to resume VB's installation, cause it to freeze again.

I wish to obtain one of two:

1) get it installed correctly ( it is the 2nd time it happened- cause re-installation of Ubuntu )

2) Somehow to uninstall it, and stop this problem.

Guy

Comment: How long did you let the 'freeze' continue before rebooting? On some systems, dkms takes a while....

Comment: about 20 minutes untill killing it